# How can I legally allow modders to use my tools that are dependent on licensed assets?

Tags: unity, modding, licensing

I am making a moddable game with Unity. I actually have working system for serializing/deserializing items etc.

For purpose of easy item creation in Unity, I made editor-only windows that help you with process of creating objects and setting their properties. The thing is these windows are dependent on bought asset.

My question is how to let users create their own items with those editor-only windows? I wanted to make project open source (so they can put it in Unity and just do it as I did) but obviously I can't put licensed files there.

Comment: What kinds of dependencies are these? Can you substitute them in some way?

Comment: @DMGregory these editor-windows are highly dependent on the bought asset

Comment: Then it sounds like you're very likely out of luck. ☹ I can't think of any other solution with the limited details we have right now. If you can share more specifics, maybe that will reveal an opportunity specific to that situation.